# Нужна ли запятая перед «как» в обороте со сказуемым?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли в данном предложении запятая перед "как"?

**Расскажем, как получать дополнительный доход.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверим наверняка добавлением слов:

`Мы вам расскажем про то, как вам можно получать дополнительный доход.` - сложноподчинённое предложение, в котором обязательна запятая.

При меньшем количестве слов правило не меняется и это всё так же сложноподчинённое предложение (просто короткое).

Вывод: нужно.